# git ignore in the root folder does not disregard vs code files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have included `.vsconfig` in my `gitignore` file, but sourcetree still registers and tracks it.

Why does this happen? Does the ignore file only ignores this in the root folder? Do I need to add `/` before or after `.vsconfig`?

Comment: Did you added to git  `.vsconfig` before excluding it by `.gitignore`?

Comment: If a file is already tracked, you need an extra action to make git "forget" about it. See the duplicate QA.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.